# Is this a realistic evolution for a flatworm-like species?

Tags: biology, evolution, anatomy

I have made two simple diagrams, each detailing the difference between two of my genuses (yes this is on purpose); **Kuroribranch** and **Ennapoda**. Kuroribranch is extremely similar to an Earth flatworm. Ennapoda is a strange squid-sepia flatworm mix - eventually becoming similar to Earth's Octopoda. These organisms have 9 tentacles, evolved from fins after duplicating a segment of their body. Their sensory organs (such as brains) have migrated towards the anterior end of the body, becoming a head, in a process known as cephalisation. Additionally, the length of their body has been compressed, and their posterior tail has thinned into a tentacle-like structure (the 9th foot) - however it is different from the other tentacles in its purposes.
The attached image depicts Kuroribranch on the left, and Ennapoda on the right. Different colours mean different tissues, for example purple means nerves and orange means muscle fibres.

[image: This image depicts two drawn organisms - on the left being a genus known as Kuroribranch, and on the right being a genus known as Ennapoda.]

Comment: Closer to crab is always the correct direction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcinisation

Comment: it's not relevant to your actual question, but if "ennapoda" is intended to be Greek for "nine-footed ones", parallel to "octopoda", the correct form would be "enneapoda"

Comment: whilst this is a common meme and not unreasonable for worldbuilding purposes, irl carcinisation is only really attested in the crustaceans (and almost entirely within decapods specifically), not even all of arthropods, and definitely not in flatworms (which diverged from crustaceans as long ago as snails (to which they're closely related) did, and not long after the deuterostomes (including all vertebrates) did

Comment: That's actually planned! Kuroribranch is a genus where the cladogram will split - on one path the Enneapoda will evolve, and on the other the species will develop a calcium carbonate shell on their backs. This lineage will be called "Hoplosdorsum", and will be the main ancestor to all bugs and crustaceans on my planet :)

Comment: @Tristan Definitely, I'm learning about the naming of organisms. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: I feel like it's necessary to provide additional information. These organisms are able to photosynthesize, and Kuroribranch can grow between 30-50cm in size, while Enneapoda can grow between 10-20cm in size. 
The light blue-teal colour in the diagram represents reproductive cells, and the green colour represents the digestive tract. You may notice that yes, they share the same sac - the gonads sense sperm inside the sac and retract all fluid inside, hoping to store it for later. This is similar to a queen bee.

Comment: Well flatworms evolved, didn't they?

Answer (score 8):

I can't see any issues. during the Cambrian "explosion" when multicellular life really started to diverge, there was plenty of variety in body layout: like [Hallucigenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucigenia):

and [Opabinia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opabinia):

Both have bilateral symmetry which is good or at least was...

Answer (score 7):

I don't see anything which blatantly shout "let's take a U turn (or a sharp left) in the evolutionary path!".

Given the right environmental conditions what you have depicted it's plausible. At the end, both octopuses and humans have evolved from the same unicellular organism floating in the primordial soup, which is a larger divergence than what you have in your two species.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that's true. These two organisms are intended to be more closely related, unlike your comparison to Octopuses and Humans. Thanks for the answer though, I definitely agree.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really possible to answer from the limited details in the question.

But if it is to be plausible the major question you need to address is how energy dynamics work in your species. Flatworms are heavily limited by their body structure: lacking any true body cavity. They cannot have lungs, and they have no means of blood flow. That means their ability to get oxygen and nutrients to their tissues is very limited, which puts hard limits on their size and how active they are. This is made worse by their single exit digestion system which limits the amount of food they can efficiently extract nutrition from. With these limitations the evolution and diversification of the group into the forms you describe whilst remaining flatworm-like seems unlikely.

But perhaps you don't intend on carrying over those distinctive features of flatworms?

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how I can make blood vessels in this flatworm-like organism, now. Maybe some of the fibers begin flowing liquid throughout the system to help supply oxygen?

Comment: @AxobitMelodies: there are many ways a circulatory system could evolve, the problem as I see it is that the _lack_ of such a system is one of the distinguishing features of flatworms and one of the reasons that their body form is how it is. Change that and I'm not sure what you mean by flatworm-like, and you need a reason why the morphology has been retained when the restrictions that result in that morphology are gone.

Comment: @JackAidley would it be a fair simplification to say that being flat makes sense for a creature without a circulatory system and a creature with a circulatory system would probably not evolve to remain flat?

Comment: @Pahlavan Obviously there are a handful of flat creatures with circulatory systems so it is possible but, yes, generally creatures with circulatory systems have evolved to have the bridge variety of shapes that allows.

Comment: *large variety of shapes. Stupid autocorrect

Answer (score 2):

The Kuroribranch looks like a very plausible line of adaptation towards a more pelagic form perhaps as a consequence of neoteny i.e. retention of larval or juvenile characteristics. For example, let's say your flatworm taxonomic group starts out as a small zooplanktonic larval form that disperses to new habitats. That could explain  those pseudopod-like wing things you have drawn. It is certainly possible that retaining the larval characteristics into adulthood might provide an evolutionary advantage in certain circumstances. Perhaps some of the Kuroriobranch develop into full fledge zooplankton living their lives entirely in the water-column while others evolve to have a life cycle with complete metamorphosis from a pelagic stage back to a benthic stage that has true parapodia like a polychaete. You COULD
develop a similar line of reasoning for the Ennapoda and perhaps even tie the evolution of the two classes together. This is a really cool idea. Hope you continue it.

Answer (score 2):

### Evolution doesn't have a plan, so each variation must be good enough to allow genes to multiply each time.

The remarkable variety of life on our own planet is the result of many incremental adjustments, each single one providing the organism either a benefit or a better chance of multiplying.

Factors which benefit each variation may include:

- Natural Selection - do the variations decrease the chance the organism will die before it mates?
- Habitat Advantage - does the variation allow the organism to find / stumble upon new environments devoid of its competitors, to allow it to multiply more?
- Sexual Selection - the particular variation makes the organism 'sexier', or more appealing to a mate. In your case, does the shifting of certain features appear advantageous to a mate, and desirable? Think 'signals' where doing so may give the impression of speed, strength, or even the opposite, where a male may be more encumbered but strangely attractive because it is perceived to be comfortable enough to survive.

Over time, your organism may indeed have the characteristics of your target animal - there is no reason this would not be the case, as long as at each step / generation there is an advantage as described above.